# javascript how to fill a return from values of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I don't know how to formule the question(title), so I'll just say it here, and maybe someone may help or provide a new point of view about it.
I'm working with `discord.js` and I want to check if user has a role/roles from a message

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'ADMIN')) {
        console.log('I am admin');
    }
});
```

Now my idea is to make this a polymorphism functions, because if I want to check two roles I have to do this:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'ADMIN') || message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'Other')) {
        console.log('I am admin');
    }
});
```

And I would like to move this `if` condition to a function and it will check it even if I want to check one or more `permissions.

For now I have tried to deal with it, but nothing, and stopped here... Maybe someone can give me some advice or other point of view. The idea is to prevent duplicate code and an `if` as long as the width of my monitor.

```
function hasRole(msg, permissions, condition = 'or') {
    if (Array.isArray(permission)) {
        if (condition === 'or') {
            permissions.forEach(function (element) {

            });
//            permission.join('||');
            return msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === permissions) ||
                msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === permissions);
        } else if (condition === 'and') {

        }
    }

    return msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === permissions);
}
```

If you want to check [DiscordJS DOCS](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=roles).

Response:

```
function checkPermissions(msg, permissions, condition = 'or') {
    if (condition === 'or') {
        return msg.member.roles.some(r => permissions.includes(r.name));
    } else if (condition === 'and') {
        return msg.member.roles.every(r => permissions.includes(r.name));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkPermissions(msg, permissions, condition = 'or') {
    if (Array.isArray(permissions)) {
        if (condition === 'or') {
            return msg.member.roles.some(r => permissions.includes(r.name));
        } else if (condition === 'and') {
            let value = false;
            permissions.forEach(permission => {
                value = !!msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === permission);
            });
            return value;
        }
    }
    return !!msg.member.roles.find(r => r.name === permissions);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
function hasRole(msg, permissions, condition = 'or') {

    //harmonise @permissions to array, if isn't already one
    permissions = Array.isArray(permissions) ? permissions : [permissions];

    //if or, at least 1 member role must be present in @permissions
    if (condition === 'or')
        return msg.member.roles.some(role => permissions.includes(role));

    //if and, all member roles must be found in @permissions
    else
        return permissions.every(perm => msg.member.roles.includes(perm));

}
```

Comment: In this case `includes` is not a function. But I can follow you, I think I can use [https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection?scrollTo=every](http://example.com) will try it. Thanks